# String.Split - Omit empty array elements OR below a certain length

Tags: c#

I'm aware of `RemoveEmptyEntries`, but how can I make split() also omit elements that are smaller than X charaters.

```
string s = "test:tessss:t:pas";
```

Pseudo-Code:

```
s.Split(':', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//Where 2 is the minimum length to not be omitted.
```

Is the only solution to make a loop and remove the ones smaller than X ? Isn't that a bit non-efficient?

Comment: What makes it inefficient? Sounds like a perfectly good solution to me.

Comment: It is indeed possible to write a dedicated method that returns only parts above the minimum length that is faster than a solution that first splits, then filters. But the chance that this particular operation is a bottleneck in your code (and thus even worth optimizing) is vanishingly small, so don't sweat it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var minLength = 2;
var entriesArr = s.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 .Where(s => s.Length >= minLength)
 .ToArray();
```

Kind of makes the use of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` redundant.

You could make an extension method:

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static string[] Split(this string s, char sep, int minLength)
    {
        return s.Split(sep)
                .Where(s => s.Length >= minLength)
                .ToArray();
    }
}
```

then you could:

```
var str = "bar b foo";
str.Split(' ', 2)...
```